# How to send large Flux<Object> to Spring Web Flux via POST?

Tags: reactive-programming, angular5, server-sent-events, spring-webflux, eventsource

Currently, working on developing reactive web applications for data processing application. I have a back-end service written in **Spring WebFlux** accepts 
 `applcation/stream+json` as a media type.

I am trying to send a array of json documents in the request body. The number of documents depends on the number of products being uploaded. Typically (250 to 10000) payloads can be uploaded. I want to send these payloads to the URL,
 `POST http://localhost:8080/products` using **Angular 5**.

**Request Body**

`[{
    "id": "B001",
    "description": "T-Shirt",
    "price": 250
},
{
    "id": "B002",
    "description": "Shirt",
    "price": 220
},
{
    "id": "B003",
    "description": "Jeans",
    "price": 210
},
......]`

The problem is, some times takes only 25 or 49 or 55 or 0 payloads in the backend. However, I am able to see sending all the payloads in the request (Browser Network terminal).

I think, i have to send these request using Event Source in angular 5, However, I am unable to find some examples. Your inputs are much appreciated!!.

Thanks!!

Comment: the EventSource API is powered by Server Sent Events - so this only supports server to client messages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, in the above case, i am want to send from client(frontend) to server(Webflux) .